# Adding Values to Dictionary With Integer Data Type

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a program that checks if an item is in a list. I am getting an error regarding the data type I am trying to import.

What is strange is that I can successfully add the same data type in the start of the code, but later in the code a similar with same data type fails.

I tried using dic4.update(str(d)) instead of dic4.update(d)

```
dic1={1:10, 2:20}
dic2={3:30, 4:40}
dic3={5:50,6:60}

dic4 = {}

for d in (dic1,dic2,dic3):
    dic4.update(d)
# adds all items from dict1,dict2, and dict3 to dic4

print(dic4)

dic5={3:30, 9:45}

for d in dic5:
    if d in dic4:
        print("Already in set")
    else:
        print("Added to set")
        dic4.update(d)
# error occurs on above line

print(dic4)
```

I expected the value {9:45} to be added to the dictionary 'dic4' like so:

```
{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60}
Already in set
Added to set
{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60, 9: 45}
```

Output:

```
{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60}
Already in set
Added to set
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/19083/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Dictionary Practice/dictExercise3.py", line 20, in <module>
    dic4.update(d)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `for d in dic5:`.... `d` is an int, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for d in list(dic5):
    if d in list(dic4):
        print("Already in set")
    else:
        print("Added to set")
        dic4[d] = dic5[d]
```

Answer (score 0):

In first loop `for d in (dic1,dic2,dic3):` you iterate over touple of dict's, so with each iteration `d` is a `dict`.

On the other hand in second loop you iterate over one dict and with each iteration `d` becomes key of `dic4`, in this case it will be **integer** keys from 1 to 6. You cannot update dict with integer but you could do  `dic4[d] = dic5[d]` to solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
for d in dic5:
```

Is not doing what you expect.
It iterates over the keys of dic5.

So when you try to

```
dic4.update(d)
```

You try to update dic4 with a key. The update command expects however a dict.

What would work is:

```
for key, val in dic5:
    if key in dic4:
        print("Already in set")
    else:
        print("Added to set")
        dic4[key] = val
```

Answer (score 0):

so the issue is you are trying to update the dictionary with a key only. `d` in your case is holding the key. When using the update method you need to give the key value pair.

Here is a fix

```
dic1={1:10, 2:20}
dic2={3:30, 4:40}
dic3={5:50,6:60}

dic4 = {}

for d in (dic1,dic2,dic3):
    dic4.update(d)
# adds all items from dict1,dict2, and dict3 to dic4

print(dic4)

dic5={3:30, 9:45}

for d in dic5:
    if d in dic4:
        print("Already in set")
    else:
        dic4[d] = dic5[d]
        print("Added to set")

# error occurs on above line

print(dic4)
```

Not a big deal but you should give the user feedback after the action has been done and not before in anticipation that it will work as expected. `print("Added to set")`